# How to disable checksum checks in SBT with new coursier integration

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to retrieve some packages from the [Confluent Maven Repo](http://packages.confluent.io/maven/).
Unfortunately for some files there, the `.sha1` checksum files are incorrect.
I tried working around this by specifying

```scala
update / checksums := Nil
```

in `build.sbt` but this doesn't prevent SBT 1.3.0 from checking the checksums and failing.
I assume this is due to Coursier being the default downloader now and the above code only impacting Ivy.

What's the correct way to disable checksum checking in SBT 1.3.0 onwards?

Answer (score 1):

> What's the correct way to disable checksum checking in SBT 1.3.0 onwards?

That sounds like [wrong checksum with spark-sql 2.4.4 (Scala 2.12) #5381](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5381) that I've just reported that has been bugging me for months.

A solution is to disable coursier using `useCoursier := false`.